# Gradle uploadArchives publishes POM twice

Tags: gradle, publishing

Gradle tries to publish maven's POM twice (through `uploadArchives` task)

I have multiproject build with `apply from:`s where specified how to publish my artifacts (`publish-jars.gradle`):

```
task sourcesJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allSource
}

build.dependsOn(sourcesJar)

artifacts {
    archives sourcesJar
}

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(url: 'releases repo') {
                authentication(
                    userName: rootProject.properties.get('artifactory.username'),
                    password: rootProject.properties.get('artifactory.token')
                )
            }

            snapshotRepository(url: 'snapshots repo) {
                authentication(
                    userName: rootProject.properties.get('artifactory.username'),
                    password: rootProject.properties.get('artifactory.token')
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

def installer = install.repositories.mavenInstaller
def deployer = uploadArchives.repositories.mavenDeployer

[installer, deployer]*.pom*.whenConfigured { pom ->
    pom.project {
        packaging 'jar'
    }

    pom.withXml {
        asNode().dependencies.'*'.each {
            if (it.scope*.value != null) {
                it.scope*.value = 'compile'
            }
        }

        asNode().dependencyManagement.dependencies.'*'.each {
            if (it.scope*.value != null) {
                it.scope*.value = 'compile'
            }
        }

        def repos = asNode().appendNode('repositories')

        project.repositories.findAll { it.name != 'MavenLocal' }.each {
            def repo = repos.appendNode('repository')
            repo.appendNode('id', it.name)
            repo.appendNode('name', it.name)
            repo.appendNode('url', it.url)
        }
    }

    if (project.hasProperty('pomConfigurer')) {
        pom.withXml(pomConfigurer)
    }
}

install.dependsOn build
uploadArchives.dependsOn build

task 'publish-snapshot'() {
    dependsOn uploadArchives
}

task publish() {
    dependsOn uploadArchives
}
```

and I have module which contains only parent pom (`:my-project:parent`):

```
dependencyManagement {
    generatedPomCustomization {
        enabled = true
    }
}

ext.pomConfigurer = {
    // some pom configuration
}
```

and finally I have root project build.gradle:

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'maven'
  apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
}

subprojects {
  apply from: file('publish-jars.gradle')
}
```

Is it gradle bug, or am I doing something wrong?

UPD: Gradle output

```
> Task :my-project:some-module:compileKotlin
> Task :my-project:some-other-module:compileKotlin
> Task :my-project:some-another-module:compileKotlin
> Task :my-project:some-yet-another-module:compileKotlin
> Task :my-project:one-more-module:compileKotlin
> Task :my-project:last-module:compileTestKotlin
> Task :mkGitTag
##teamcity[setParameter name='env.release_tag' value='v2.1.1-rc20']

> Task :my-project:parent:uploadArchives
Could not transfer artifact groupname:parent:pom:2.1.1-rc20 from/to remote (https://releases repo): Failed to transfer file: https://releases repo/groupname/parent/2.1.1-rc20/parent-2.1.1-rc20.pom. Return code is: 409, ReasonPhrase: Conflict.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':my-project:parent:uploadArchives'.
> Could not publish configuration 'archives'
   > Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact groupname:parent:pom:2.1.1-rc20 from/to remote (https://releases repo): Failed to transfer file: https://releases repo/groupname/parent/2.1.1-rc20/test-parent-2.1.1-rc20.pom. Return code is: 409, ReasonPhrase: Conflict.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 22s
43 actionable tasks: 43 executed
```

Comment: You applied `maven` plugin twice - but this should not cause the problem. What is the gradle output? I mean tasks that are run? You should see there that it is run twice.

Comment: @Opal Fixed but it did not help :( In output I have single call to :uploadArchives